# Use static property of extended class in super()

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, static, es6-class

Suppose we have the code

```js
class A {
  static foo = 1;
  constructor() {
    console.log(A.foo);
  }
}
class B extends A {
  static foo = 2;
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
new A(); // prints "1"
new B(); // also prints "1", but make it print "2"
```

Here the constructor of `A` is accessing `A.foo`. When `A` is extended to `B` with a new value of `foo`, the constructor still prints `1`, the value of `A.foo`, when really I want it to print the value of `B.foo`.

How would I modify this code such that the constructor prints the `foo` property of the **current** class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `constructor` property to get access to the class itself, then you can refer to the static property from that.

```js
class A {
  static foo = 1;
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.constructor.foo);
  }
}
class B extends A {
  static foo = 2;
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
new A(); // prints "1"
new B(); // also prints "1", but make it print "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

the [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) calls the constructor of the super class.

What you can do is the following

```js
class A {
      static foo = 1;
      constructor(...args) {
        if(args.length == 1){
          console.log(args[0].foo)
        }
        else{
        
        console.log(A.foo);
        }
      }
    }
    
class B extends A {
  static foo = 2;
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args); // calls A.foo not B.foo
  }
}
new A(); // prints "1"
new B(B); // pass the Class to it self as an arg
```